Moving with a questionable advisor
I know variations of this question have been asked before, but it's nice to get input on a specific situation. I'll try to keep this as brief as possible.
I am a PhD student at reputable institution A in the US. My advisor, Dr. Jill (pseudonym), was hired as an assistant professor at a better university, institution B. I have a B.S. in the field and am very early in my Ph.D. career.
Dr. Jill has a few issues:

She has very little diplomacy, making her criticisms and remarks difficult to endure
Despite having just 4 students, she is so busy with other obligations that she does not spend sufficient time with each of them (including myself)
She is unprofessional. In a recent meeting, she lamented previous students by name to her current students. In other meetings, she bluntly criticizes students in front of the group for minutes at a time

In addition, she recently "fired" one of her Ph.D. students after this student accepted the offer from institution B. While I don't have all the details, the student's perspective was that Dr. Jill was a bad leader / manager / advisor, and from my own observations and supporting stories from others, I believe this to be the case. In response, another student has decided to stay at institution A.
I have reservations about Dr. Jill. I don't think she is a good leader, and I have told her multiple times that I don't want to do the research that she is directing me to do (which is unrelated to what I originally signed up for). I do not trust her poor management and lackluster social skills to carry me through a Ph.D., but I know that I am independently capable.
To now, your answer is probably "don't go!" I would perhaps stay at institution A, but I'm not sure that I can find another advisor whose work would be interesting enough. I was also looking forward to living in a new place. I considered staying at institution B until I get my master's degree, but I don't know how long that would take. I also considered moving, working for a semester, and then finding a non-academic job to work.
What do you think? I will likely move to the new city regardless of if I'm enrolled at institution B. But how should I game plan for Dr. Jill? I appreciate your insights!

Why would you move to the new city?

Direct, correct criticism need not necessarily be couched 'diplomatically'. Personally, I prefer blunt, accurate assessments. I still recall the response of a mentor to something I proposed - they said "Well, Jon, that's just bullshit." And they were right. And I never tried to bullshit them (or anyone else) again. Clear, direct, accurate feedback need not be 'diplomatic'.

How do you know you would be accepted to University B? Does Dr. Jill have a line of funding for University B that she has asked you to accept and work with her? Also, what about Universities C,D, E, F....and Z, that are also options for other universities?

Honestly it sounds like you don't like or have any respect for Dr. Jill, and she probably doesn't like that you don't want to do the research she is directing you to. Let her start over at her new institution with students who are interested in her research instead of going with her and bringing your disrespectful attitude that will poison the new group dynamic before it even starts. You should be fine without her. You are obviously a supremely talented PhD student, Dr. Jill is obviously a bumbling fool who has little achievements beyond getting a faculty position then getting poached.

@Dr.K - from what I've seen, for a move like this, who the professor is bringing with them is part of the hiring package. Students close to being done finish up at the old institution, new students are part of the deal to bring the professor over.

@AzorAhai-him- I am looking forward to living in a new place. Although originally for school, if I decided not to pursue the PhD I would still live there and find a job.

@JonCuster Direct, correct criticism is indeed acceptable. Unfortunately, her criticism is neither direct nor correct. When she criticized me, I asked her for specific details about what I could do better, and she chose to sweep the criticism under the rug. Furthermore, her criticism is sometimes too personal to be helpful. Critique the painting, not the artist, especially not in front of a group.

@Dr.K I have been accepted to University B with funding. I'm hesitant to move somewhere else for universities C, D ... Z because I don't want to roll the dice on another advisor. Furthermore, and perhaps I should have mentioned it in the post, I haven't fallen in love with research like I hoped I would.

@R1NaNo Dr. Jill told me I would be working on X, which her and her lab are familiar with. I was excited to work on X, and agreed to join the lab under the condition that's what I would do. Dr. Jill then pivoted my work to Y, which neither she nor I are familiar with and which was never discussed when I agreed to join the lab. Y is not close to X - it is in fact extremely far away. As for my attitude, you're right that I shouldn't poison the lab - that would be unfair to her and her students. However, the last part of your comment is nonsense, and I don't know why you have to be aggressive.

Are you accepted to University B with funding because your advisor is moving there? If so, I suspect most other profs would be leery of "poaching" a student of their new hire.

@JonCuster Yes. It would not be possible for me to switch advisors without causing lots of headaches and resentment.

@fallacy Yes my statement was a little harsh and bordering on the absurd. However, I want you to take a look at the comments you have made about your advisor in your post and in response to others. Honestly, it looks like you completely detest this person and have zero respect for them. This is not healthy, and frankly it is also not fair to continue either to you or to them. As to your note about changing topics. This happens often, especially with younger faculty whose initial ideas are refined, and pressure is on to produce and get tenure. If you really dont like the research, change groups

Seems like you have a few options:

Stay at institution A and find another advisor. You say this is a no-go, and it seems like you've already mentally discarded this option.
Follow Dr. Jill to institution B and continue working with her. From your post, this seems like a very bad idea.
Follow Dr. Jill to institution B, then find another advisor. I would speak directly to institution B about this possibility, and also think about who your advisor at B would be. This will require extreme tact, since it's likely Dr. Jill will hear about this. But you probably don't want to make the jump only to learn that you aren't actually able to switch advisors.
Apply as a transfer student to institutions B and C.  Your advisor leaving is an iron-clad "excuse," so wanting to transfer won't seem suspicious at all. Maybe you can get in somewhere you're more excited about. But this may delay your graduation by a year or so.
Abandon your PhD.

Only you can decide which of the last three options is best.


I have reservations about Dr. Jill. I don't think she is a good leader, and I have told her multiple times that I don't want to do the research that she is directing me to do (which is unrelated to what I originally signed up for). I do not trust her poor management and lackluster social skills to carry me through a Ph.D


your answer is probably "don't go!"

Indeed; don't go.

Indeed, learning to listen to the little voice in your head rather than trying to "rationally" over analyze things is a skill to learn. It applies to many situations in life.
